# BLE - Modbus TCP IP in iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, modbus

What is the best way to communicate with a remote device using Modbus over TCPIP via Bluetooth BLE in iOS? Has anyone experienced this yet? As there is almost to no information available on the internet.

Thanks